# Display Update button & save values in database

Tags: save

We are displaying table grid as below image, in last column you can see commission as 10 & 0.

[image]

i need to provide an Update button below that and provide an option to edit 10 & 0 , so if we click on "update" button, it should save in database.

[image]

we are using below code to display table grid.

**php**

```
function getDesignerCollection()
{

$user_home = new USER();

    $stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users");
    $stmt->execute(array(":uid" => $_SESSION['userSession']));
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stmt->execute();

    $i=0;
    while($data = $stmt->fetch())
    {       
        $responce[$i]=array($data['userID'],
                      ucfirst($data['name']),                 
                      $data['commission1'],
                      $data['joining_date']);
        $i++;
    }   
    echo json_encode($responce);
}
```

**script**

```
var __TEST_DATA__=eval('<?php echo getDesignerCollection();?>');
var grid_demo_id = "myGrid" ;
var dsOption= {
    fields :[   
        {name : 'userID'  },    
        {name : 'name'  },
        {name : 'commission1'},         
        {name : 'joining_date'} 

    ],
    recordType : 'array',
    data : __TEST_DATA__
}   
function my_renderId(value ,record,columnObj,grid,colNo,rowNo)
{
    var no= record[columnObj.fieldIndex];
    return "<input type='checkbox' value='"+record[0]+"' name='userID'/>";
}
var colsOption = [  
    {id: 'userID' , header: "Customer Id" , width :"90",renderer : my_renderId},
    {id: 'name' , header: "Designer Name" , width :"140"},
    {id: 'commission1' , header: "commission1" , width :"120"},
    {id: 'joining_date' , header: "Customer Since" , width :"120"}


];
```

now to provide an update button , i am trying below code :

**form**

```
<form method="post" name="update" action="updateform.php" />

commission1:

<input type="text" name="commission1" />
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="update" />
</form>
```

**updateform.php**

```
$sql = "UPDATE tbl_users SET commission1 = '$commission1' WHERE userID= :uid";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
```

where i need to use form code to display "update" button below values 10 & 0

I am new to php & tried lot before posting here, but did't got any idea related to my code.

Comment: `':ud'?` that is failing you for 2 reasons.

Comment: hes not using `PDO`... and therefore no `execute()`

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry, that typo in question, i am using `:uid` in code......

Comment: you're going to have to update your question with the real syntax then, otherwise others may post answers based on that.

Comment: @Blueblazer172 please help me for displaying `update` button below values 10 & 0 , so that i can check about saving values......

Comment: Thanks @Fred-ii- updated the question......

Comment: `':uid'?` that wasn't what I meant. You're using PDO with 2 different placeholders and quotes around it. same for the other one; why the `?` here? and the RDBMS is unknown. You using mysql? other?

Comment: @abcd your sql statement is wrong in many ways

Comment: Please update your post with any error messages you may be getting and/or explain specifically what is not working with your existing code so others can better understand your issue.

Comment: and where is `$commission1` defined? Your question has too many errors. Sorry, but I'll have to pass on this one.

Comment: @Fred-ii- corrected sql statement , also we are using this code : `$data['commission1'],` to fetch value of commission

Comment: I agree with Fred on this one, Why are you using $comission1 within your query but then :uid further along?

Comment: `':uid'` remove the quotes, I already said that ;-) Just `:uid` here.

Comment: @Option i am new to this php & mysql, is this correct : `$sql = "UPDATE tbl_users SET commission1` ?

Comment: you're also not doing anything with that bind.

Comment: You should also change $commission1 to :commission1 and then bind that param along with the :uid

Comment: no, just using that without a `WHERE` clause will update your entire db.

Comment: I suggest you go read the manual on PDO prepared statements http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php

Comment: @Fred-ii- updated question removed quotes for `uid`, i referred some wrong tutorial, they mentioned that, please tell what sql statement i need to use here to update only commission ?

Comment: @abcd your satement is still not correct

Comment: `$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM tbl_users");
    $stmt->execute(array(":uid" => $_SESSION['userSession']));
    $row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $stmt->execute();` that whole statement doesn't have the bind for it. That tutorial you read, I'd surely like to know the URL for it and to see if any of you made any mistakes. If that tutorial is indeed correct and you went and changed a lot of the syntax, then you need to go back to it and read the manual on the link I gave you, good luck; I have to let go now ;-) cheers